# SELinux CentOS-7, problems when to create Tablespace PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, centos, selinux

When I try to create a tablespace in /mnt/sdb/pg, with SELinux enabled,
the following error occurs:

postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE ts_table OWNER postgres LOCATION '/mnt/sdc/pg';

ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory 
"/mnt/sdb/pg": Permission denied

Disabling SELinux the tablespace is created without problems ...
setenforce 0

I don't want to disable SELinux

Comment: What command did you issue to elicit the "Permission denied" message?

Answer (score 0):

Commands:

su postgres 
psql 
postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE ts_table OWNER postgres LOCATION '/mnt/sdc/pg';